# Change default keybinding for TableViewer

Tags: java, swt, jface

By default a JFace TableViewer moves the selection up and down when the user presses the up or the down arrow key. This makes sense most of the time, but in my application the business logic will be different.

How can I override this behavior? I tried adding a KeyListener and it gets called, but the default action still happens: selection changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out I have to use a TableViewerFocusCellManager along with a CellNavigationStrategy. I expected the FocusCellManager to be a property of the TableViewer, but it is not. Apparently the FocusCellManager does the wiring behind the scenes.

```
    CellNavigationStrategy navigationStrategy = new CellNavigationStrategy() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldCancelEvent(ColumnViewer viewer, Event event) {
            return true;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean isNavigationEvent(ColumnViewer viewer, Event event) {
            return false;
        }
    };
    TableViewerFocusCellManager focusCellManager = new TableViewerFocusCellManager(tableViewer, new FocusCellOwnerDrawHighlighter(tableViewer), navigationStrategy);
```